# μετὰ τοῦτο ἄκουε (Symposion.215)

Tags: greek, translation-check, grammar-identification, greek-translation

I have a question about [the following extract](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Plat.%20Sym.%20215&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0173) ([Platon's Symposion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symposium_(Plato)), 215)

> *[Alcibiades describes Socrates as a Silenus's statue and as Marsyas, a satyr.]* ὅτι μὲν οὖν τό γε εἶδος ὅμοιος εἶ τούτοις, ὦ Σώκρατες, οὐδ᾽ αὐτὸς ἄν που ἀμφισβητήσαις: ὡς δὲ καὶ τἆλλα ἔοικας, **μετὰ τοῦτο ἄκουε**. ὑβριστὴς εἶ [...]

my translation:

> On the one hand, that you are similar to them, at least in terms of appearance, that is what you cannot dispute, O Socrates. But that on the other hand you also look like the rest of them, listen to this again. You're a mocker [...]

What bothers is me is the exact meaning of "μετὰ" in "μετὰ τοῦτο ἄκουε" : litteraly, something like "hear after that", **but after what ?**
My own translation ("listen to this again") sounds plausible but nothing allows me to treat μετὰ as an adverb meaning "again".

So...

- is "μετὰ" an [adverb](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=meta%5C&la=greek&can=meta%5C0&prior=e)/oikas&d=Perseus:text:1999.01.0173:text=Sym.:page=215&i=1#lexicon) (~ "then") here ? "Then, hear that";
- is "μετὰ" a [preposition](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=meta%5C&la=greek&can=meta%5C0&prior=e)/oikas&d=Perseus:text:1999.01.0173:text=Sym.:page=215&i=1#lexicon) (+acc ~ "after") ? "After that, hear ";
- for the sake of completeness, ["μετὰ" can't be a preposition introducing the 
  complement of ἀκούω](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=a%29%2Fkoue&la=greek&can=a%29%2Fkoue0&prior=tou=to&d=Perseus:text:1999.01.0173:text=Sym.:page=215&i=1#lexicon);
- for the sake of completeness, "μετακούω" doesn't exist;

Any help would be appreciated !

---

**[Full extract:](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Plat.%20Sym.%20215&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0173)**

> Σωκράτη δ᾽ ἐγὼ ἐπαινεῖν, ὦ ἄνδρες, οὕτως ἐπιχειρήσω, δι᾽ εἰκόνων. οὗτος μὲν οὖν ἴσως οἰήσεται ἐπὶ τὰ γελοιότερα, ἔσται δ᾽ ἡ εἰκὼν τοῦ ἀληθοῦς ἕνεκα, οὐ τοῦ γελοίου. φημὶ γὰρ δὴ ὁμοιότατον αὐτὸν εἶναι τοῖς σιληνοῖς τούτοις τοῖς [215β] ἐν τοῖς ἑρμογλυφείοις καθημένοις, οὕστινας ἐργάζονται οἱ δημιουργοὶ σύριγγας ἢ αὐλοὺς ἔχοντας, οἳ διχάδε διοιχθέντες φαίνονται ἔνδοθεν ἀγάλματα ἔχοντες θεῶν. καὶ φημὶ αὖ ἐοικέναι αὐτὸν τῷ σατύρῳ τῷ Μαρσύᾳ. ὅτι μὲν οὖν τό γε εἶδος ὅμοιος εἶ τούτοις, ὦ Σώκρατες, οὐδ᾽ αὐτὸς ἄν που ἀμφισβητήσαις: ὡς δὲ καὶ τἆλλα ἔοικας, μετὰ τοῦτο ἄκουε. ὑβριστὴς εἶ: ἢ οὔ;

**[Translation:](http://classics.mit.edu/Plato/symposium.html)**

> And now, my boys, I shall praise Socrates in a figure which will appear to him to be a caricature, and yet I speak, not to make fun of him, but only for the truth's sake. I say, that he is exactly like the busts of Silenus, which are set up in the statuaries, shops, holding pipes and flutes in their mouths; and they are made to open in the middle, and have images of gods inside them. I say also that hit is like Marsyas the satyr. You yourself will not deny, Socrates, that your face is like that of a satyr. Aye, and there is a resemblance in other points too. For example, you are a bully [...]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds very similar to *Crito* 49e2-3:

> εἰ δ’ ἐμμένεις τοῖς πρόσθε, τὸ μετὰ τοῦτο ἄκουε.

Which translates to:

> If you abide by [what we agreed] beforehand, listen to what follows.

Literally, "τὸ μετὰ τοῦτο" means "the after that."

Although the article τό makes the *Crito* passage more obvious, it seems pretty clear that this is what is going on in the *Symposium* as well.

"μετὰ τοῦτο" clearly should be construed together as preposition + object, meaning "after that." "That," in this case, refers to the similarity with respect to appearance ("τό . . . εἶδος") that he just made. In order to hear the other similarities--Alcibiades chides Socrates--"listen to what follows."

Comment: Thank you very much. As far as I know, Symposium.215 and Crito.49 seem to be the only two extracts where we can read the words "μετὰ τοῦτο ἄκουε".

Comment: Using the TLG, I also found the following with different forms of *akouein*: *Philebus* 66e1, *Protagoras* 355a5, *Laws* 832b8.